# Fancybox won't work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, fancybox

i am trying to call a fancybox iframe from an iframe to parent. 
It works fine in Firefox, but it just won't work in Google Chrome.
I am using: fancybox v2.1.5

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.video').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        parent.parent.$.fancybox({
            href: this.href,
            width: 560,
            height: 315,
            type: 'iframe',
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                opacity: 0.3
                }
            } 
        }); 
    });     
}); 
</script>
</head>
```

and this is how i am trying to call it to parent:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/3l8MwU0IjMI?autoplay=1', type: 'iframe'});" class="video">open youtube video</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `<a class="video" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3l8MwU0IjMI?autoplay=1"` because inside the script you are already setting `href: this.href` otherwise fancybox won't be able to process `javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open....` as `href`

Comment: it still doesn't work :/ thank you anyway!

Comment: This works with Chrome. Check the source code